# Angular. html injecting from tinymce

Tags: html, css, angularjs, tinymce

In my admin panel i got tinymce textarea. I want to preview all my changes. 
i get html from tinymce

```
$scope.text_in = tinymce.get('myTextAreaName').getContent();
```

and it looks like:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;">AAA</h1>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">BBB</h3>
```

I'm using ngSanitize and my element where i want to inject HTML

```
<div class="new" ng-bind-html="text_in"></div>
```

Thats looks ok, BUT. I got html markup without inline styles. All other styles from css works fine. 
When i inspecting element there are

```
<h1>AAA</h1>
<h3>BBB</h3>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Angular documentation you can by pass the sanitize.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.%24sanitize)